# what tag should i use for text? html5

Tags: html, css

What tag should i use for small amount of text. For example it is good practise to use p tag for every "small" text like here "username" and pasword" or for day/month/year, should i use also p tag?

```
<div class="login-area">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text">   
    <p>Password:</p> 
    <input type="password">
</div>
```

Comment: Use `<label></label>` for those

Comment: read up on tags here (check the left column to browse the different tags): https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site. There are tutorials and books available that will teach you HTML5 and the various tags, as well as the common uses for them.

Comment: Suggest using `<span></span>` or `<label></label>`

Comment: What tag to use for text? The short answer is _it depends_. As suggested, `<label>` would make sense above. For other use cases there may be other semantically preferred elements. See [this HTML Elements Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) and specifically the parts on Text Content and Inline Text Semantics :o)

Comment: Tags, along with classes, should generally describe _what something **is**_ -- that thing, as others pointed out _**IS**_ the label for an input field.  After you've marked what things _are_, then describe how they _appear_ with CSS rules.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
<label for="name">Your Form label</label>
<input type="text" name="name">   

<label for="password">Your Form label</label>
<input type="password" name="password>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Others have suggested `<label></label>` tag is other option that you can use.

Some of it's use cases are as follows:

```html
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
```

```html
<label>
   Name : <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</label>
```

```html
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
```